# Filtering a collection with out for each loop

Tags: c#, collections, lambda

I have all collection of MovieDTO object and also a collection of MovieDTO of user favourite movie.

I want to add a boolean flag Selected =true in each object of all movie collection, if the perticular item is exist on User Favourite.

I wish to do it with some lambda expression or some Func or some way instead of writing
two for-each loop.

```
public class Movie{
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public DateTime ReleaseDate{get;set;}
 public string Director {get;set;}
 public int Id{get;set;}
 //more property
}

//This class is mainly used to highlight the favourite movie in UI
public class MovieDTO{
 public string MovieName{get;set;}
 public boolean Selected{get;set;}
 public int Id{get;set;}
}

List<Movie> AllMovies = MyService.AllMovies();

List<MovieDTO> UserFavouriteMovie = MyService.GetUserMovies();

List<MovieDTO> allMovieDTO = AllMovies.Select(x => new MovieDTO
{
    Name=x.Name,
    //Selected=true/false => here i want 
     // to check if x is exist in UserFavouriteMovie collection
}).ToList();
```

Any suggestion with out using two for each loop here?

Comment: Not really possible without knowing the definitions of `Movie` and `MovieDTO` in at least some detail.  How do we know if they're actually the same?  Is it based on the `Name` string, is there an ID field or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take all of the names and put them in a `HashSet` for efficient searching, and then just use `Contains` for each item.

```
var names = new HashSet<string>(UserFavouriteMovie.Select(movie => movie.Name);

List<MovieDTO> allMovieDTO = AllMovies.Select(x => new MovieDTO
{
    Name=x.Name,
    Selected = names.Contains(x.Name),
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the HashSet be initialised from UserFavouriteMovie List

Comment: @RichardSchneider Probably, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we can only compare user favourites and movies by `name`:

```
var allMovieDTO = AllMovies.Select(x => new MovieDTO
{
   Name = x.Name,
   Selected = UserFavouriteMovies.Any(f => f.name == x.name)
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is doing a linear search through a list, which is horribly inefficient.  Also `Contains` will do exactly the same thing in 
less code.

Comment: @Servy, you mean this will be same as iterating each item even if it got matched already?

Comment: @Servy, UserFavouriteMovie is List<> so we have to do a linear search.

Comment: @user1909604 For each item in `AllMovies` it needs to iterated through `UserFavouriteMovies`, from the start, to look for the item.  This means, on average, it's going through half of the items in the favorite movies *for each movie*.  That's a lot of iterating, particularly in a case where you just don't need any of that.  You just need to use a more appropriate data structure that is designed for fast searching, such as a `HashSet`.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Well, first off, no, that's not strictly true.  You could do a binary search after sorting the data.  Second, you'll end up saving a substantial amount of time creating a new data structure that can be efficiently searched and then using that instead.

Comment: The `Any` method short circuits.  If a match is found, then it immediately returns true.  @Servy, is hinting that Dictionary or HashSet would be a better structure than a list.

Comment: @RichardSchneider How is it hinting?  I said so very explicitly.  Also note that `Contains` short circuits as well.  Even with short circuiting, it's still *much* slower than using a `HashSet`.  (Including the time to create the structure.)

Comment: @Servy, I wrote 'hinting' comment after your first comment.  But you posted your second comment before mine. Sorry.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Note that I had also already posted my answer at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You specifically asked to use Func so although I am sure there are better ways to approach this.  Here is some code...

If the Lists are large this may take some time since it will run a search on UserFavoriteMovie for every AllMovies.

```
        List<Movie> AllMovies = new List<Movie>();

        List<MovieDTO> UserFavouriteMovie = new List<MovieDTO>();

        List<MovieDTO> allMovieDTO = AllMovies.Select(x => new MovieDTO
        {
             MovieName = x.Name
             , Selected = new Func<bool>(() => {

                 if (UserFavouriteMovie.Exists(a => a.Id == x.Id))
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     return false;
                 }


             }).Invoke()
        }).ToList();
```

However, you dont need to use Func.  Just do this...

```
  , Selected = UserFavouriteMovie.Exists(a => a.Id == x.Id)
```

Answer (score -1):

The detail of Movie and MovieDTO are not listed. So I just write a rough demo to achieve your requirement.

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> b = new List<int> { 3, 2 };
List<int> c = a.Where(o => b.Contains(o) ).ToList();
```

You could make some changes to let it fit your project.

Comment: This will be highly inefficient as you're doing a linear search on the second list for each item in the first.  Also note that with two lists of `int` you can just use `Intersect` instead of `Where`/`Contains` (anytime you see that pair consider using `Intersect` instead) but that isn't an option for the OP as the lists aren't of the same type.  Additionally, he doesn't want to filter items that don't exist, he wants a boolean value indicating if it exists.

Comment: Oops, I forget to consider the efficiency. XD Thank you for your suggestion.